# Do not replace words which contain apostrophe or &, in python

Tags: python, regex

I have the following setup:

```
fword = "don"
comment_true = "Don is bad. Don't eat nails. Carl&Don. Don&Carl. Don, Don."
comment_false = "Don't do this"
replace_with = "[ANONYMISED]"
```

First, I would like to check whether `fword` is in `comment_true` or `comment_false`.

Next, I would like to replace `fword` with `replace_with`.

The resulting string should be:

**`comment_true:`**

`"[ANONYMISED] is bad. Don't eat nails. Carl&Don. Don&Carl. [ANONYMISED], [ANONYMISED]."`

**`comment_false:`**

`"Don't do this"`

At the moment for the first task I am using:

```
 True if re.search(r'\b%s\b' % fword, comment) else False
```

For the second task I am using

```
re.compile(r"\b%s\b" % fword, re.IGNORECASE).sub(replace_with, comment)
```

However for this problem they are insufficient, as the parts of the contractions like 'don't', or Carl&Don are matched. This question is not simple whitespace check as I only need to escape some of the symbols.

See the example here:
https://regexr.com/42bc8

How can I achieve this?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I guess that the accepted answer proves, that this question is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Regex: `(?:^|(?<=\s))don(?=,|\.|\s|\Z)`

[Demo](https://regexr.com/42bdo)

Comment: thanks a lot. However this query does not match the words if there is a `.` or `,` in the string. How can I escape that? I will update the example for these cases as well.

Comment: @johnnyheineken, I've updated my answer to handle `,` and `.`